# Display RTSP stream in Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, rtsp, ip-camera

I am working on a project that involves displaying video feed from an IP camera using Adobe AIR. I know that Flash does not have a native support of `RTSP` protocol and therefore I am evaluating all possible routes I can take to solve this issue:

1. Use [Adobe Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-professional.html) to convert incoming RTSP stream to RTMP and then [use](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?799405-RESOLVED-AS3-Steam-RTMP-LIVE-video-WITHOUT-FLVPlayback-Component) Flash API (`NetConnection` & `NetStream`) directly.
2. Write a custom class to fetch, decode and display the stream in adobe AIR. [I am unable to confirm if this is possible due to insufficient info on the net]
3. Give up on RTSP and instead [fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848855/how-to-render-ip-camera-video-with-socket-by-actionscript) JPEG/MJPEG sequence of images and display them in AIR relatively easily but with doubtful *live* performance. [due to JPEG/MJPEG refresh interval of IP camera and same interval separately in AIR]
4. Use [DirectShow Video Source Filter for JPEG and M-JPEG IP Cameras](http://alax.info/blog/1216) to process the JPEG/MJPEG stream, create a virtual Webcam device (the filter does this automatically) and then use `Camera` class to display the video feed in AIR.
5. Use [webcam 7](http://www.webcamxp.com/home.aspx) - A software designed to handle RTSP, JPEG/MJPEG and other stream protocols for many camera brands/models. It installs a driver in system that creates a virtual camera, and that all the other applications can then use as a normal webcam. 
   Unfortunately this software is buggy and often becomes unstable (could be with my particular camera model only though) and might even crash.

Are there any better, easier  options that might not require any third-party software?

**EDIT:**

In case anybody else bumps into same problem:
As suggested by Rudolfs Bundulis, I decided to write a `NativeProcess` (ANE) that uses [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) to fetch the RTSP stream data, transcode it, and feed it to Flash player.
You might want to look at these for more specific steps:

http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2013/02/converting-video-with-ffmpeg-and-adobe-air/ 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6N7eN9wvAGQ

Comment: Hey.
Sorry for waking up old thread, but did you ever got to a working solution? I'm in a need of a similar thing, to play multicasted/broadcasted video stream in as3 flash project. Do you have any further info about it? Is the ANE available anywhere to get? :) Thanks

Comment: Hi,  Unfortunately I don't have any code available but this tutorial should give you a basic idea [http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2013/02/converting-video-with-ffmpeg-and-adobe-air/](http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2013/02/converting-video-with-ffmpeg-and-adobe-air/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the route described in option 2 - write a Adobe AIR native extension (ANE) that uses FFMpeg to handle the RTSP stream, decode it and pass the RGB data back to AIR for rendering. The hardest part would be compiling FFmpeg if you need cross platform functionality, however, since you mention DirectShow that is Windows only, then I assume you are bound to Windows. [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) provides prebuild FFmpeg libraries for Windows, Stackoverflow has a lot of topics on decoding a stream using FFmpeg and then all you need is a callback to AIR and you're good.

Comment: Thank you. No cross platform functionality needed in this case. I will dig into modifying FFmpeg libraries I guess.

Comment: You don't need to modify them. Just make an AIR native extension, put something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715170/receiving-rtsp-stream-using-ffmpeg-library inside to receive and decode the stream and you're good.